# Can i use bluetooth on FlutterFlow?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I'm making android app what communicate with atmega128 and hc-06.
but I couldn't find a widget that supports Bluetooth. so, Is there any custom widget that supports Bluetooth?

Comment: flutter_blue: ^0.8.0 try this packge

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, FlutterFLow does not have a built in Bluetooth widget. You can use a custom widget from https://pub.dev/packages?q=bluetooth
(Look for the widget with the function you need)

Guide to create custom widget in FlutterFlow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jM2gwA2VHyc

[image]